# He changed nature itself

Tags: grammar

What does this sentence mean?

> He changed nature itself.

This is the sentence from the book *Main Street* by Sinclair Lewis.

Comment: The previous sentence describes how he changed the inhabitants, and the [next sentence](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Main_Street/LO9aAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Main+Street+by+Sinclair+Lewis+changed+nature+itself&pg=PA198&printsec=frontcover) says *"A mountain which had borne nothing but lilies and cedars and loafing clouds was by his Hustle so inspirited that it broke out in long wooden sheds, and piles of iron ore to be converted into steamers to carry iron ore to be converted into steamers to carry iron ore."* So not just the people but the landscape too: nature itself.

Comment: Is your difficulty with the word "itself".  Do you understand what "He changed nature" means?

Comment: @JamesK Yes, itself.

Answer (score 0):

The word "itself" is an emphatic pronoun.  It doesn't change the meaning of the sentence, but it emphasises the word "nature". It marks this word as special, interesting or surprising in some way.

Emphatic pronouns are formed exactly the same way as reflexive pronouns. But they don't have any reflexive meaning.  They follow a noun to emphasise it.

So "He changed nature itself". Means "He changed nature."  But this is surprising.  To change nature is an exceptional change, and the speaker wants to draw your attention to this fact.

Consider this example

> When I visited the White House, I met the Secretary of Defense, then I met the First Lady, finally I met the President himself!

The speaker want to emphasise and draw you attention to this last word.

> The President himself wrote this letter.

Again the speaker want to emphasise the word president, as this is the interesting and surprising fact.

On the other hand

> The President shot himself in the foot.

This is reflexive pronoun, and doesn't emphasise anything.